# RichTextBox change text of color

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I have RichTextBox control with some BASIC TEXT entered. I wish to customize it in a way that, when user will enter or paste some text this would have different font color than the BASIC TEXT.

i was changing SelectionBackColor prperty on KeyDown event, but it occurs also when user tries only to copy part of BASIC TEXT.

```
 private void richTextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        RichTextBox richTextBox1 = sender as RichTextBox;
        richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.LightCoral;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `KeyDown`, use `TextChanged` event:

```
private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RichTextBox richTextBox1 = sender as RichTextBox;
    richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.LightCoral;
}
```

Comment: But Textchanged event is working in my system i have checked it.......... please check once again

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
private void richTextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.V)
        {
            richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.LightCoral;

        }
        else
        {
            richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.White;
        }
    }
```

Comment: it occured to me that pasting text, doesnt invoke selection event so:    if(e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.V) 
        { 
            richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.LightCoral; 
} does nothing....

Answer (score 0):

```
private void richTextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.V)
    {
        richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.LightCoral;

    }
    else
    {
        richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.White;
    }
}
```